# cURL - usage of -d (POST) in config file?

Tags: curl

I'm trying to use the -d switch with curl and a config file. As a one-liner, the following works perfectly. I see the contents of the file as a POST on the web server.

curl -d "@file.txt" http://192.168.1.1

I'd like to do the same but using a config file and the -K switch. I've tried creating the following config file, named input

data = "@file.txt" http://192.168.1.1

and then using:

curl -K input

But I'm receiving the error 'curl: no URL specified'

I've tried searching, but I cannot find any answers. I'm fairly new to curl scripting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `curl` man page, [regarding the `-K` flag](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-K):

```
Note that to be able to specify a URL in the config file, you need to specify it using 
the --url option, and not by simply writing the URL on its own line. So, it could look
similar to this:

url = "https://curl.haxx.se/docs/"
```

So your config file should be:

```
url="http://192.168.1.1"
data="@file.txt"
```